# Automatically recorded activities missing aggregated activity summary from google fit api

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

Walking/Running/Biking are examples of activities automatically recorded on android phones with google fit installed. I've been trying obtain these activities from the Fit API for Android with the following query...

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
    .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)
    .bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build();

DataReadResult dataReadResult = Fitness.HistoryApi
    .readData(googleApiClient, readRequest)
    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

The results of this query provides a list of activities with the start time and duration of that activity. This is exactly what I am expecting but for some reason it doesn't return the data that is automatically recorded by the google fit application. It seems to only return items that fall under one of these conditions:

- activity was manually recorded from google fit interface
- "session" was recorded using the Sessions API
- activity was manually added using the History API (didn't test this but this is my assumption)

**Question**

Is anyone aware of how I might need to modify my query to obtain data that is automatically recorded by the google fit application on my device? It might be the case that this specific data just isn't available for use (which would be strange because I can get the steps that are recorded automatically).

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? I'm facing the same issue right now but with the REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up a subscription to passively save the data? Here's how:

```
Fitness.RecordingApi.subscribe(mClient, DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                if (status.getStatusCode()
                        == FitnessStatusCodes.SUCCESS_ALREADY_SUBSCRIBED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Existing subscription for activity detected.");
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Successfully subscribed!");
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "There was a problem subscribing.");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: hmm.. yeah i've tried that and for some reason i'm still unable to get the data. My assumption was that I would get  any walking/running/biking data from the point i activated and forward.

Answer (score 1):

I get activity segment data just fine. My read request is different from yours so I copied yours and read a week's worth of data and received no data sets. In this past week I have not manually inserted any data sessions. My belief is that the `bucketBySession` is your issue. I ran 3 tests, each `DataReadRequest` described below assuming a time range is also set (1 week for me):

1. `read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)`; no aggregation, no bucketing. **Result**: Good data.
2. `aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)` with `bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)`. **Result**: No data sets or buckets.
3. `aggregate(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, DataType.AGGREGATE_ACTIVITY_SUMMARY)` with `bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)`. **Result**: Good data

In my opinion the [`bucketBySession` documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/DataReadRequest.Builder.html#bucketBySession(int,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) isn't very clear that it would exclusively return data that is part of a `Session`, but that seems to explain the results from my 3 tests as well as your list of conditions that you noticed.

**Note** also that I have the Google Fit app installed and I'm not sure if this same data would be automatically recorded/subscribed to if it were not.